# MongoDB aggregation to join 2 fields not working

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have 2 mongo db collections, 'Contacts' and 'Messages'. Both collections share the phone number field(Primary/Foreign Key relation in SQL).

Contacts collection has this field as follows:

```
{
  "phone": "+192******",
  "name": "test"
}
```

and Messages as follows:

```
{
  "Tel": "tel:+192******" 
}
```

I want to aggregate the 2 collections such that I can have this nested document:

```
"text": "text sent by user",
"contact": {
   "phone": "+192******",
   "name": "test"
}
```

So far, I have tried the following aggregation but it doesn't work:

```
cursor = messages_client.aggregate([{
     '$lookup':
       {
         'from': "contacts",
         'let': { 'phone': "$phone"},
          'pipeline': [
              { '$addFields': { 'phone_number': { "$substr": [ "$Tel", 4, -1 ] }}},
              {'$match': { "$expr": { '$eq': [ '$phone_number', '$$phone']}}}
          ],
           'as': 'contact'
       }}
  ], allowDiskUse=True)
```

Could someone kindly help me? I'm using pymongo and Python3 if that is helpful.

Comment: First part of your question says join b/w `User` and `Messages` collection, but in your query u are performing join b/w `Messages` and `contacts` collection?

Answer (score 0):

Found some help from [`$indexOfCp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/index.html) operator, for anyone with a similar problem.

```py
cursor = messages_client.aggregate([{
     '$lookup':
       {
         'from': "contacts",
         'let': { 'phone': "$phone"},
          'pipeline': [
              {'$match': { "$expr": { '$gt': [{ "$indexOfCP": ["$Tel", "$$phone"]}, -1]}}}
          ],
           'as': 'contact'
       }}
  ], allowDiskUse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
db.messages.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            'phone_number': { "$substr": ["$Tel", 4, -1] }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "contacts",
            let: { "phone": "$phone_number" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$phone", "$$phone"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "contact"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$contact" }
]);
```